# Grub2 doesn't detect windows 8. [OpenSuse 42.1]

Tags: boot, windows, grub2, dual-boot, opensuse

So I've recently installed OpenSuse 42.1 on my laptop. It was installed in a 20Gb of unallocated disk space. My laptop came with FreeOS preinstalled. I've installed Windows 8 and recently openSUSE, however when the boot loader starts (I think it's Grub2 but I'm not sure) it doesn't show Windows 8. Also I'm pretty sure my motherboard has BIOS and not UEFI.

I've run the Boot Info Script which shows [**this**](http://pastebin.com/HbqvFd9r) results.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed Linux distro to many computers and never faced any problems with grub, if it didn't work for the first time then running "sudo update-grub" always fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows 8/Linux dual boot system I've been using EasyBCD as a boot manager for 3 years now and have never had problems with it.